# Strip Leading Zeroes from Date

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

todays_date = datetime.datetime.today()

todays_date = todays_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

goal:

I want to return: 2022-4-9
Currently returning: 2022-04-09

I tried doing this, but it gives me an `Invalid format string error`:

```
todays_date = todays_date.strftime('%Y-%-m-%-d')
```

The documentation that I looked at is located here:

> https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing you're on Windows, so you'll want `today.strftime('%Y-%#m-%#d')` (note the `#` instead of `-`)

Comment: For the record, the unofficial guides are frequently out of date and/or inaccurate. [Python's official `strftime` docs provide a useful table of features](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), and the short version is, they're all zero-padded. As the duplicate notes, on certain platforms there are cheats around this; odds are the guide you looked at inadvertently documented platform-specific code. Personally, I'd recommend keeping the zeroes (which makes the output string sort by date), but the duplicate provides options if that's unacceptable.

Comment: I'm using Selenium to pull a report and the dates in the report URL have no padded zero, that's why I needed them off.